# calculating $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{l+100}{l}0.5^l 0.5^{100}$ and $\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}l \binom{l+100}{l}0.5^l 0.5^{100}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Is there any formula for calculating
$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\binom{l+100}{l}0.5^l 0.5^{100}$ and
$\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}l \binom{l+100}{l}0.5^l 0.5^{100}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$(1-z)^{-m}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+m-1}{n}z^n
$.

Differentiate this to get the other.

Comment: Interesting. Where does this formula come from? Any intuition behind it?

Comment: It's the generalized binomial theorem. Look it up.